# It is possible to use Tensorflow C++ API in QT project?

Tags: c++, qt, tensorflow, qt-creator

I trained a Tensorflow model for image classification using the Python API, then i saved the model checkpoint.

Now I want to load this model in a QT(C++) project.

After looking into documentations, I found that to use Tensorflow C++ API you need to create a  project inside a clone of the TensorFlow github repository, then build it with Bazel, who is not possible in my case.

Is there a way to include tensorflow library in my QT project ?

Comment: There is, however, [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc)  project that builds and installs TF C++ API

Answer (score 4):

You need bazel (or CMake) to build the tensorflow library, but once it is compiled you are free to use whatever tool you like and treat it like an external library.

Believe me, once you have compiled tensorflow, the last thing you want to do is add it to your project and rebuild it accidentally. This baby takes *time*.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I built the library with bazel, now i want to integrate it in QT, should i import the libtensorflow_cc.so ?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable with QT creator but you should import this library in your project just like any other external library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Compile tensorflow project as a library (dll) and include it into qt project.

Comment: thank you. my project developped in linux (Ubuntu 14.4)  with QtCreator editor. what file should i import ??

Comment: @Sv Sv: Could you have any example or tutorial about tha

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use *make* instead of *bazel* to build the TensorFlow library for your target platforms.

You can find more information on building TensorFlow with a Makefile at the [TensorFlow GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile) project.

You can also have a look at this [guide and open-source example project](https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/machine-learning-add-image-classification-for-ios-and-android-with-qt-and-tensorflow) for Image Classification and Object Recognition with Qt and TensorFlow. It describes how to build TensorFlow using *make* and integrates it to your Qt project using the *QMAKE* build system.