# Linking libtensorflow_cc.so file to QT project

Tags: c++, qt, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow_cc library in QT creater
I tried linking the libtensorflow_cc.so in .pro file but I'm still unable to access the header files.

test.pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -ltensorflow_cc
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/lib/
```

test.cpp file:

```
#include <tensorflow/core/platform/env.h>
```

error :

```
tensorflow/core/platform/env.h: No such file or Directory
```

I have added the path of the .so file to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Is there anyway to include the tensorflow library and use the header files in QT.
[This is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194458/it-is-possible-to-use-tensorflow-c-api-in-qt-project#comment82656443_45194532) but it didn't quite help me.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your absolute path to `env.h` ?

Comment: error solved. I added the paths to header files in INCLUDEPATH. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so
```