# How to include tensorflow c++ ".so" file in makefile?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, makefile

I have created a .so file using the bazel command:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-fPIC" :tensorFlow.so
```

Following is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -g -W -O3 -Wall -Wshadow \
-Wno-long-long -Wpointer-arith -D_REENTRANT \
-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DLINUX2 \
-I ./acl/lib_acl_cpp/include 
BASE_PATH=./acl
LDFLAGS = -L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl_cpp/lib -l_acl_cpp \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_protocol/lib -l_protocol \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl/lib -l_acl \
-lpthread -lprotobuf -ljsoncpp
redisConnection: redisConnection.o
    g++ ./redisConnection.o ./UnifiedMetric.pb.o ./getMapFromFeatureDistribution.o ./featureStats.o $(LDFLAGS) -o redisConnection 
redisConnection.o: redisConnection.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) redisConnection.cpp -o redisConnection.o
```

I went through various links but couldn't find any way. How do I include the .so file file created in the makefile and what other things have to be added?

Comment: My GCC is rusty, but I think you just add it to the `redisConnection: redisConnection.o` g++ line which is your link step. The -l flag means 'link a file that starts with lib and ends with .so or .a', so typically you'd call your lib 'libtensorflow.so' and link it with '-ltensorflow'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the paths to header files in INCLUDEPATH.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688754/linking-libtensorflow-cc-so-file-to-qt-project) might be the exact replica for your problem.